# Java Out of memory heapspace

Tags: java, heap-memory

I am getting Out of memory  error when trying to run  MasterTestSuite in my eclipse enviroment

I am using

```
-Xms256m -Xmx650m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

I could increase my XMX even more, but if I increase it more than 700m, I get `Could not reserve enough space for object heap`

So looks like, in my environment, the maximum amount of heap space that the program is able to allocate is 650m.

But when I look at my C drive, I have about 30gb free space left.

Is there something I need to do so that I can increase my XMX to say 1024m and not get the  `COuld not reserve enough space for object heap` error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your on Windows, what's the settings for the size of your Virtual Memory (Control Panel -- System -- Advanced system settings -- Performance -- Advanced tab -- Virtual memory)? Increase that some more so that Windows can swap from RAM to your page file. (Changing it will require a reboot.) That will slow things down a bit, as the swap file (on disk) is much slower than RAM.

Comment: Currently i have "Automatically manage pagingfile size for all drives " checked true

Comment: Typically, Windows will make a page file (swap file) which is smaller than your physical memory; the old rule of thumb was to manually set it to physical RAM x 1.5. I'd go for at least physical RAM times two, if you've a lot of free disk space and not much RAM.

Comment: My computer has 8GB ram. Im not running any other programs at all except to get my MasterTestSuite run. My C drive has 45031 MB of free space available. Given that , you are advicing me to set my page size maximum to 8gb*2 = 16gb size. Right?

Comment: You've got lots of RAM, so you're problem is somewhere else. The settings you're mentioning: `-Xms256m -Xmx650m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m` are for Eclipse, right? Is this Eclipse 32-bit or 64-bit? 32-bit or 64-bit Java/JDK installed? What JVM are you running when starting Eclipse?

Comment: My eclipse is 32-bit.  My JAVA JDK installed is 64 bit.

Comment: You should change the JVM which Eclipse is using to the Java 64-bit JDK JVM. Change in eclipse.ini: something like this (adjust to your setup) `-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk7/bin/javaw.exe` (-vm and the path on separate lines).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51511/discussion-between-jedison-and-barry)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but the heap is being stored in RAM, not on your hard disk, unless you're using some weird sort of virtual memory.

(edit) I realize that answer isn't super helpful. If you *are* trying to use virtual memory, you should check your operating system and verify how much disk space is being set aside for virtual memory.

Comment: The entire purpose of virtual memory is to abstract away physical implementation details (for example, whether pages are stored in RAM or swapped to disk).

Comment: You're right, of course. However, in my (admittedly limited) experience, you normally wouldn't use that for something like a test suite, so I guess I was a little confused when he was looking at his hard drive.